# Form submit buttons not passing values

Tags: forms, post, submit

I have a basic form that includes 3 submit buttons.

```
<form action="/signups/wizard/location" id="SignupForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>
Street: <input name="data[Location][street]" maxlength="200" type="text" value="">
Apartment: <input name="data[Location][apartment]" value="">
City:<input name="data[Location][city]" maxlength="50" type="text" value="">
<div class="submit">
    <input name="Previous" type="submit" value="Previous">      
    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
    <input name="Cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel">  
</div>
</form>
```

When I submit that form, I expected the input fields for submit buttons to pass their data to $_POST, however I only see Location in the array.

Here are $_POST's contents:

```
array(
    '_method' => 'POST',
    'data' => array(
        'Location' => array(
            'street' => '',
            'apartment' => '',
            'city' => ''
        )
    )
)
```

**UPDATE**
I disabled javascript and the values appear in $_POST.  Is there an easy way to determine what script could be removing this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit, this JavaScript was included on every page by a previous developer.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Arg! Just did exactly the same thing! Thanks for posting your solution :-)